# Jquery multiselect values not UTF-8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

Im using Jquery multiselect for a project.The issue i am having is that special char is not rendered well when choosen. For instance in my picklist i have the value "Anadarko E&P", when i select this value, it is displayed as "Anadarko E&P". 
[image]

Do anybody know how to prevent this?
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: how you have coded the value of checkbox? is it `Anadarko E&P`

Comment: no, the value is an Id, something like 00A8828917gghJkk

Comment: so you must be picking html code beside the checkbox? if yes, you can  change the code to `Anadarko E&P` from `Anadarko E&amp;P`

Comment: Try .replace('&amp;','&'); or try $('div').html(EnocdedValue); will work. But i don't know your code structure.

Comment: Does anyone using erichynds jquery Ui multiselect, having this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.Find the code below :

```
          $j(selector).multiselect({
        header: true,
        multiple: false,        
        selectedList: 1,
        classes: "jq_over",
        selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
          for(var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++){
            return $j(checkedItems[i]).siblings().text();
          }
       }
    }).multiselectfilter();
```

I had to modify the selectedText attibute to take the label and this works correctly

Answer (score 0):

It will only work when the selectedList = 1.
For other cases (e.g. selectedList = 4), i modified as below,

```
selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
    var selectedList = 4;
    if(checkedItems.length > selectedList)
    {
        return checkedItems.length + " selected";
    }
    else
    {
        var selectedTextArr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++)
        {
            selectedTextArr.push($(checkedItems[i]).siblings().text());
        }
        return selectedTextArr.join(', ').replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
    }
}
```

However, to solve the issue from the root cause, modifying the jquery.multiselect.js may be a way...

```
  if(numChecked === 0) {
    value = o.noneSelectedText;
  } else {
    if($.isFunction(o.selectedText)) {
      value = o.selectedText.call(this, numChecked, $inputs.length, $checked.get());
    } else if(/\d/.test(o.selectedList) && o.selectedList > 0 && numChecked <= o.selectedList) {
      value = $checked.map(function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get().join(', ');
    } else {
      value = o.selectedText.replace('#', numChecked).replace('#', $inputs.length);
    }
    value = value..replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<");  // newly added
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem just today and I found another solution that I think is better, I post it here for future:

```
var multiSelect = $("#myField").multiselect({selectedList: 3});
multiSelect.multiselectfilter({autoreset: true});
multiSelect.data("echMultiselect")._setButtonValue = function(value){
    this.buttonlabel.html(value);
}
```

The issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/issues/473) and it wasn't fixed to avoid XSS vulnerabilities, the complete official anwser is:

> HTML everywhere leaves the code more open to XSS vulnerabilities. The
>   original developer intentionally set it this way to make the default
>   behavior safe, if you need unsafe behavior then you can override the
>   method and add html. There is documentation on how to do this in the
>   the Customization section of the docs.
>
> Since this issue was opened, the line described above was actually
>   changed from html() to text() as well.

Anyway in my scenario, I think I could ignore this kind of problem, because my `<option>` elements couldn't be modified by users.

Note, the original implementation in [jquery.multiselect.js](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/blob/master/src/jquery.multiselect.js) is:

```
// this exists as a separate method so that the developer
// can easily override it.
_setButtonValue: function(value) {
  this.buttonlabel.text(value);
},
```

And is clearly specified that could be easily overrided.

PS: It works with any option of `selectedList` attribute.